# Difference between `my_func<T: MyTrait>` vs `my_func<T> where T: MyTrait`

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Whats the difference between

```
my_func<T: MyTrait>(...) {...}
```

and

```
my_func<T>(...) where T: MyTrait {...}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is written with an explicit `where` clause, the other isn't.

Okay, okay; if you want to be picky, the differences are:

- You can't introduce a generic parameter with a `where` clause.
- You can't constrain anything *other* than generic parameters in the generic argument list.

But in terms of what changes when you move constraints from the generic argument list to a `where` clause, they're the same.

Comment: This is it? They are completely interchangeable?

Comment: Yes... provided we're talking about things that are valid in the generic argument list in the first place.  I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted to know; thanks!